# How to tell Manim to write LaTeX using MikTeX instead TinyTeX?

Tags: python, manim, miktex, tinytex, choco

I have a working Manim CE v0.17.2 installation, but I accidentally uninstall TinyTeX using `choco uninstall tinytex` in PowerShell (as administrator). As a result, of course, Manim can't write any LaTeX with the following error:

```
RuntimeError: latex failed but did not produce a log file. Check your LaTeX 
installation.
```

So, I tried to reinstall it using `choco install tinytex` in PowerShell. However, it failed to install, so I want to change Manim such that it uses MikTeX (which is installed) instead of TinyTeX. Is there any help for that?

The failed installation was occured due to this error (which I don't understand):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> choco install tinytex
Chocolatey v1.3.1
Installing the following packages:
tinytex
By installing, you accept licenses for the packages.

tinytex v2023.04 [Approved]
tinytex package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
The package tinytex wants to run 'chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
Note: If you don't run this script, the installation will fail.
Note: To confirm automatically next time, use '-y' or consider:
choco feature enable -n allowGlobalConfirmation
Do you want to run the script?([Y]es/[A]ll - yes to all/[N]o/[P]rint): A

File appears to be downloaded already. Verifying with package checksum to determine if it needs to be redownloaded.
Hashes match.
Hashes match.
Extracting C:\Users\LENOVO IDEAPAD S145\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\tinytex\2023.04\TinyTeX-1-v2023.04.zip to C:\tools...
C:\tools
Running tlmgr path add
Warning: conflicting [pdf]tex program found on the system path in C:\Users\LENOVO IDEAPAD S145\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\ C:\texlive\2023\bin\windows; not fixable in user mode.
0
Updating tlmgr
DO NOT CLOSE THIS WINDOW!
TeX Live infrastructure update in progress ...
Detailed command logging to "C:\tools\TinyTeX\temp\update-self.log"
self update: texlive.infra (66512 -> 66822)
Infrastructure update finished successfully.
You may now close this window.
0
Installing Extra Packages
Installing previous user installed packages
ERROR: The term 'C:\Users\LENOVO' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
The install of tinytex was NOT successful.
Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\tinytex\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.

Chocolatey installed 0/1 packages. 1 packages failed.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).

Failures
 - tinytex (exited -1) - Error while running 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\tinytex\tools\chocolateyinstall.ps1'.
 See log for details.
```

So, I guess my choice is either fixing this or telling Manim to use MikTeX instead of TinyTeX.

Comment: Try `pip uninstall manim` and then `pip install manim`...

Comment: The problem is caused by spaces in the name of the folders. In particular "LENOVO IDEAPAD S145". LaTeX has known problems with spaces in the names of the files or folders. Unfortunately that folder is where miktex and tinytex are installed...

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, definitely tried both and it works now!